# HA for consul (or any distributed service) on aws in 2 availability zones

Tags: amazon-web-services, high-availability, consul

I am trying to setup consul for service discovery. We have hosted our infrastructure on AWS Mumbai region. I was going through the consul documentation where it is mentioned that when we run consul as a cluster a minimum of (n+1)/2 nodes are required to be running.

The issue is that the Mumbai region has only two availability zones. So if one zone goes down then there is a possibility that there is only one server of consul running.

So the question is that if that happens will it be possible for the agents to still serve DNS requests if I am fine with having stale results.
If no, then is there a way by which I can avoid failure with 2 availability zones.

Answer (score 0):

It is a very tricky question and a very genuine concern. In our case since we had our infrastructure in multiple regions we put the 3 master nodes in 3 different regions and it works fine for us.

I would suggest if possible go for multi-region master node configuration to be extra sure. However if you are only in one region make sure that you lock down other instance type usage in the other regions you have consul master in(and other regions which you don't utilize, a good AWS practice).